# i am sending to an array of addresses but it is showing error on transfer function

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract init {
    address[] public userAddresses;
    function addStudent(address _user) public {
       userAddresses.push(_user);
     }

     function sendToken(uint value) payable{
         for (uint i=0; i<userAddresses.length; i++) {
             userAddresses.send(value);
        }
     }

}
```

> i have used both send and transfer but nothing worked out. i have also
>   added "payable" keyword when initialising addresses array but it also
>   shows error.

[image: attached is the error]

Answer (score 3):

> Array `userAddresses` stored multiple addresses in it. So you can not
>   call `send` or `transfer` method with multiple addresses at a time so
>   you have to call like this : `userAddresses[i].transfer(value);`.

So your code should be like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract init {
    address[] public userAddresses;
    function addStudent(address _user) public {
       userAddresses.push(_user);
     }

     function sendToken(uint value)public payable{
         for (uint i=0; i<userAddresses.length; i++) {
             userAddresses[i].transfer(value);
        }
     }

}
```

> **Note:** always use `transfer` method instead of `send`. it is good practice for improve your code performance.

Comment: thank you so much to all. How can i miss it?  it worked...thanks again to all

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
userAddresses.send(value)
```

To this:

```
userAddresses[i].send(value)
```

Or better yet, to this:

```
userAddresses[i].transfer(value)
```

And get rid of the `payable` keyword in the function declaration, as it doesn't seem necessary for this function to receive funds into the contract.